# if statement for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got a code that would display the date value from a database column based on it's id but the problem is..

When I'm trying to put a new data which sets the ID to null, I'm having an error because it can't fetch the data so I've tried using if statements.

here it is

```
<input id="product_expirations" name="product_expirations" type="date" value="
<?php
if ($products){

}else 
echo $products->product_expirations;?>"
class="form-control">
```

I don't know what parameter to be put beside if $products.
please help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just write single line `if`

```
<input id="product_expirations" name="product_expirations" type="date" value="<?php echo (!empty($products)) ? $products->product_expirations; : '' ?>" class="form-control">
```

Syntax for single line `if`

```
(condition) ? TRUE: FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code sir.
It only misses a single word for my case but the code itself gave me the way to figure it out. Thanks ALOT!!!

Comment: @DarwinB.Cresidio Mark it green if help

Comment: <input id="product_expirations" name="product_expirations" type="date" value="<?php echo (!empty($products->product_expirations)) ? $products->product_expirations : '' ?>" class="form-control">